# How to get base url in meanjs?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, meanjs

i am confuse currently, how i get base url in meanjs and have any method get url base on route, this idea is originated in framework php that have all similar function. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try use this code:

```
var url = require('url') ;

app.use(function (req, res) {
  var hostname = req.headers.host; // hostname = 'localhost:12345'
  var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname; // pathname = '/app'
  console.log('http://' + hostname + pathname);
})
```

Or use
`var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;`

Refference [here](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#originalUrl)

Comment: It is very useful, in your link, i find out app.path(), it may be short method to achieve it. Thank you very much !